Why is client.query not being called in my jest test?
mocking the apollo hook
jest.mock("@apollo/client", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@apollo/client"),
  useApolloClient: () => ({
    query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: { myReturnValue: { some: "data" } },
      loading: false,
      errors: undefined,
    }),
  }),
}))

my function
  const myFunction = (input) => {
    console.log("called this?") // this 100% gets called in the test
    const data = { ...defaultData, ...input }

    return client
      .query({
        query: Query,
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        variables: {},
      })
      .then(({ data, errors }) => {
        if (!data?) {
          alert(errors)
        } else {
          console.log("in else block") // this 100% gets called in the test
          runFunction()
        }
      })
  }

in my test it is logging: "in else block"
and in my test I have:
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("My Button Text"))
await waitFor(() => expect(useApolloClient().query).toBeCalledTimes(1))

In the test output I get
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

why is this? It definitely called client.query as it got in the logs

Every time you call useApolloClient you get a new object, with a new query property, with a new mock function value. expect(useApolloClient().query).toBeCalledTimes(1) can never succeed, even if you poll, because the only existing reference to the mock is in the expectation.

@jonrsharpe thanks for that good explanation. Is there a way I can achieve what I'm trying to or is beyond the scope of a unit test?

Don't mock like this. Use a real Apollo Client instance.

The simplest fix is to not create a new object every time, e.g. useApolloClient: () => ({ -> useApolloClient: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ or just extract the value and have useApolloClient: () => fakeClient. But there are likely other approaches that would get you closer to testing actual behaviour.

As @phry said, don't mock @apollo/client module. Instead, follow the Testing React components guide.
Standing from the perspective of the user to test the component, which is equivalent to the black box test. Do not test the specific implementation(such as expect(someMethod).toBeCalled()). Instead, we should assert what the component renders. After the user interacts with the component, what changes the rendering content will be
e.g.
index.tsx:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { gql, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_DOG_QUERY = gql`
  query GetDog($name: String) {
    dog(name: $name) {
      id
      name
      breed
    }
  }
`;

export function SomeComponent() {
  const client = useApolloClient();

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  console.log(" ~ SomeComponent ~ data:", data)

  const onClick = () => {
    client
      .query({
        query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        variables: {
          name: 'Buck',
        },
      })
      .then(({ data, errors }) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>My Button Text</button>
      {data && <span>{data.dog.breed}</span>}
    </div>
  );
}

index.test.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { GET_DOG_QUERY, SomeComponent } from '.';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

describe('78333569', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mocks = [
      {
        request: {
          query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
          variables: {
            name: 'Buck',
          },
        },
        result: {
          data: {
            dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
          },
        },
      },
    ];

    render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <SomeComponent />
      </MockedProvider>,
    );

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('My Button Text'));
    expect(await screen.findByText('bulldog')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

Test result:

  console.log
     ~ SomeComponent ~ data: undefined

      at log (stackoverflow/78333569/index.tsx:18:11)

  console.log
     ~ SomeComponent ~ data: { dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' } }

      at log (stackoverflow/78333569/index.tsx:18:11)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78333569/index.test.tsx
  78333569
    √ should pass (78 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.332 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

package versions:
"@apollo/client": "^3.9.11"

